# Mathematica could not solve this complicated equations. How can we deal with it?

Tags: equation-solving

Mathematica code:

```
N[Solve[{Cos[ArcTan[1.1496/H]] == 
    Cos[0.0591 Pi]*Cos[y]*Cos[0.44167 Pi - x] + Sin[0.0591 Pi]*Sin[y],
    Cos[ArcTan[1.501428/H]] == 
    Cos[0.0591 Pi]*Cos[y]*Cos[0.4 Pi - x] + Sin[0.0591 Pi]*Sin[y],
   Cos[ArcTan[1.927918/H]] == 
    Cos[0.0591 Pi]*Cos[y]*Cos[0.358333 Pi - x] + 
     Sin[0.0591 Pi]*Sin[y]}, {H, x, y}]
 ]
```

Comment: Have you tried with $\cos(\arctan x)=1/\sqrt{1+x^2}$?

Comment: @Aretino Yes, I tried that. But unfortunately it could not work out. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps that, along with `{Cos[y], Sin[y]} -> {y, Sqrt[1-y^2]}`? Apart from that, where do the coefficients in the arguments of `Cos` and `Sin` come from? As you're using `Solve`, maybe you'd want to work with arbitrary precision numbers? If you just want a numeric solution (judging by the `N` in front of `Solve`), why not simply use `NSolve`?

Comment: Re the coefficients, I mean, perhaps there are expressions for them involving roots of rational numbers or something like that?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP You mean like this?             N[Solve[{Cos[ArcTan[1.1496/H]] ==      Cos[0.183]*Cos[y]*Cos[1.388 - x] + Sin[0.183]*Sin[y],     Cos[ArcTan[1.501428/H]] ==      Cos[0.183]*Cos[y]*Cos[1.256 - x] + Sin[0.183]*Sin[y],     Cos[ArcTan[1.927918/H]] ==      Cos[0.183]*Cos[y]*Cos[1.126 - x] + Sin[0.183]*Sin[y]}, {H, x, y}]].        I tried it but fail. NSolve maybe is the same as N[Solve[]]. Mathematica still cannot work it out. Do you have any more ideas? Thank you !

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about that last statement. Specifying the domain `Reals` (`Solve[...,{H,x,y},Reals]`) yields the message *Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help.* So I didn't mean "replace `0.0591 Pi` with `0.183`, rather where does 0.0591 come from in the first place? Is it a measured value or a number coming from some solution of a polynomial?

Comment: In the latter case it may be replaced with an *exact* expression involving some radicals represented by roots, integers and rational numbers, rather than floating point machine-precision numbers. As for substituting `Cos[ArcTan[...]]` - MMA does that automatically.

Answer (score 7):

One solution can I provide

```
f = {Cos[ArcTan[1.1496/H]] == 
   Cos[0.0591 Pi]*Cos[y]*Cos[0.44167 Pi - x] + Sin[0.0591 Pi]*Sin[y], 
  Cos[ArcTan[1.501428/H]] == 
   Cos[0.0591 Pi]*Cos[y]*Cos[0.4 Pi - x] + Sin[0.0591 Pi]*Sin[y], 
  Cos[ArcTan[1.927918/H]] == 
   Cos[0.0591 Pi]*Cos[y]*Cos[0.358333 Pi - x] + Sin[0.0591 Pi]*Sin[y]}
```

**Edit**

```
ContourPlot3D[f, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 1}, {H, 0, 10},MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
FindRoot[f, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}, {H, 1}}]
{x -> 1.89892, y -> 0.335691, H -> 2.02904}

f /. %
{True, True, True}
```

You may search for others.

```
ContourPlot3D[f, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 5}, {H, 0, 10}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
FindRoot[f, {{x, 1 + \[Pi]}, {y, 1 + \[Pi]}, {H, 5}}, MaxIterations -> 10000]
x -> 5.04051, y -> 2.8059, H -> 2.02904}

f /. %
{True, True, True}
```

**Completion**
I was interrupted. I have shown 2 solutions with H -> 2.02904. Now I show you how many solutions are available for f[x,y,H= 2.02904]. Every change of color in the Plot3D or every crossings in the ContourPlot are solutions for H =  2.02904!

```
 f[x_, y_, H_] = {Cos[
    ArcTan[1.1496/H]] - (Cos[0.0591 Pi]*Cos[y]*Cos[0.44167 Pi - x] + 
     Sin[0.0591 Pi]*Sin[y]), 
  Cos[ArcTan[1.501428/H]] - (Cos[0.0591 Pi]*Cos[y]*Cos[0.4 Pi - x] + 
     Sin[0.0591 Pi]*Sin[y]), 
  Cos[ArcTan[
     1.927918/H]] - (Cos[0.0591 Pi]*Cos[y]*Cos[0.358333 Pi - x] + 
     Sin[0.0591 Pi]*Sin[y])}  

sol = FindRoot[f[x, y, H], {{x, 1}, {y, 1}, {H, 1}}]
{x -> 1.89892, y -> 0.335691, H -> 2.02904}

soH = H /. sol[[3]]
Plot3D[{f[x, y, soH][[1]], f[x, y, soH][[2]]}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 5}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y, soH], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 5}, ContourShading -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would appreciate if you could give me some further suggestions. Using FindRoot can only get one root. What if I want to get all roots of the equations?

Comment: @user30876 You have Sin- and Cos-Functions, then you want all solutions? I can show you how to find additional solutions. See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

After substituting `0.4 Pi - x` with `x`, calling `0.0591 Pi` `a`, calling `0.04167 Pi` `b` we get a slightly simpler form of your equations:

```
With[{a = 0.185668, b = 0.04167 Pi},
    Cos[a]*Cos[y]*Cos[x + b] + Sin[a]*Sin[y] == Cos[ArcTan[1.1496/H]],
    Cos[a]*Cos[y]*Cos[x] + Sin[a]*Sin[y] == Cos[ArcTan[1.501428/H]],
    Cos[a]*Cos[y]*Cos[x - b] + Sin[a]*Sin[y] == Cos[ArcTan[1.927918/H]]
]
```

The set of solutions is clearly `2 Pi` periodic along both `x` and `y`. All we need to do, is figure out, how many roots we must find within one period. I do leave a disclaimer: this answer does not seek to prove that this set of solutions is exhaustive.

Let's look at this system graphically:

```
With[{a = 0.185668, b = 0.04167 Pi}, ContourPlot3D[{
   Cos[a]*Cos[y]*Cos[x + b] + Sin[a]*Sin[y] == Cos[ArcTan[1.1496/H]],
   Cos[a]*Cos[y]*Cos[x] + Sin[a]*Sin[y] == Cos[ArcTan[1.501428/H]],
   Cos[a]*Cos[y]*Cos[x - b] + Sin[a]*Sin[y] == Cos[ArcTan[1.927918/H]]
   }, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {H, 0.01, 5},
  Mesh -> None]]
```

> [image: Solutions]

A solution is any point where all three surfaces intersect. This seems to be possible around `{x, y} == {Pi, Pi}` and `x` close to `2 Pi` with `y` close to `0` or `2 Pi`.

For more detailed investigation, we can use the 2D contour plot with a `Manipulate` for `H`:

```
With[{a = 0.185668, b = 0.04167 Pi}, Manipulate[ContourPlot[{
    Cos[a]*Cos[y]*Cos[x + b] + Sin[a]*Sin[y] == Cos[ArcTan[1.1496/H]],
    Cos[a]*Cos[y]*Cos[x] + Sin[a]*Sin[y] == Cos[ArcTan[1.501428/H]],
    Cos[a]*Cos[y]*Cos[x - b] + Sin[a]*Sin[y] == Cos[ArcTan[1.927918/H]]
    }, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
   Mesh -> None], {H, 0, 5}]]
```

> [image: Manipulate]

After that use `FindRoot` (as in the already given answer) to investigate possible root locations separately, by specifying appropriate starting values:

```
With[{a = 0.185668, b = 0.04167 Pi}, FindRoot[{
   Cos[ArcTan[1.1496/H]] == Cos[a]*Cos[y]*Cos[x + b] + Sin[a]*Sin[y],
   Cos[ArcTan[1.501428/H]] == Cos[a]*Cos[y]*Cos[x] + Sin[a]*Sin[y],
   Cos[ArcTan[1.927918/H]] == 
    Cos[a]*Cos[y]*Cos[x - b] + Sin[a]*Sin[y]}, {{H, 2}, {x, 6}, {y, 6}}]]
```

> ```
> {H -> 2.32219, x -> 5.77348, y -> 6.20791}
> ```
>
> With a different value of `H`
>   [image: H=2.32]

By the looks of it, there'll be four roots (that is, two roots in the middle of the plot, and two more in the right-hand corners) with relatively large `(> 0.5)` values of `H`, the situation may be more complicated for small H. Obviously, replacing `H -> -H` is also a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I trig-expanded, then explicitly replaced `Cos[x]` with `cx` etc. and added defining polynomials for those.

```
exprs1 = {-Cos[ArcTan[1.1496/H]] + 
    Cos[0.0591 Pi]*Cos[y]*Cos[0.44167 Pi - x] + 
    Sin[0.0591 Pi]*Sin[y], -Cos[ArcTan[1.501428/H]] + 
    Cos[0.0591 Pi]*Cos[y]*Cos[0.4 Pi - x] + 
    Sin[0.0591 Pi]*Sin[y], -Cos[ArcTan[1.927918/H]] + 
    Cos[0.0591 Pi]*Cos[y]*Cos[0.358333 Pi - x] + 
    Sin[0.0591 Pi]*Sin[y]};
exprs2 = TrigExpand[exprs1];
exprs3 = exprs2 /. {Cos[x] -> cx, Sin[x] -> sx, Cos[y] -> cy, 
    Sin[y] -> sy};
tpolys = {cx^2 + sx^2 - 1, cy^2 + sy^2 - 1};
allp = Join[exprs3, tpolys]

(* Out[543]= {0. + 0.179093347874 cx cy - 1/Sqrt[1 + 1.32158016/H^2] + 
  0.966357710596 cy sx + 0.184603217519 sy, 
 0. + 0.303705960028 cx cy - 1/Sqrt[1 + 2.25428603918/H^2] + 
  0.93471083332 cy sx + 0.184603217519 sy, 
 0. + 0.423112888278 cx cy - 1/Sqrt[1 + 3.71686781472/H^2] + 
  0.887072226966 cy sx + 0.184603217519 sy, -1 + cx^2 + sx^2, -1 + 
  cy^2 + sy^2} *)
```

This system can be solved for `{H,cx,sx,cy,sy}`.

```
Timing[sol = NSolve[allp];]

(* Out[544]= {4.964849, Null} *)
```

Many solutions tend to have imaginary parts that are 2-3 orders of magnitude smaller than their real parts. That is to say, much smaller but not negigeable. In particular I don't know if they are artifacts of slightly bad coefficients in the input or if you simply do not get real solutions to this system. Anyway, we recover `{H,x,y}` values as below.

```
{H, ArcTan[cx, sx], ArcTan[cy, sy]} /. sol

(* Out[549]= {{-0.00114095350012 - 4.72337540363*10^-6 I, 
  1.24809419153 - 0.000221699293624 I, 
  1.75723783948 - 3.02227813013*10^-6 I}, {0.00114095350014 + 
   4.72337539431*10^-6 I, -1.89349846206 - 0.000221699293428 I, 
  1.38435481411 + 3.02227811917*10^-6 I}, {-0.00114095350014 - 
   4.72337539218*10^-6 I, -1.89349846207 - 0.000221699293224 I, 
  1.38435481411 + 3.02227813404*10^-6 I}, {0.00114095350016 + 
   4.72337537442*10^-6 I, 1.24809419152 - 0.000221699292801 I, 
  1.75723783948 - 3.02227812946*10^-6 I}, {-0.0457600565645 - 
   0.000234743067013 I, -2.27038020634 - 0.00245575865157 I, 
  1.40358621636 + 0.0000175930777828 I}, {0.0457600565645 + 
   0.000234743067016 I, -2.27038020634 - 0.0024557586516 I, 
  1.40358621636 + 0.0000175930777831 I}, {0.0457600565645 + 
   0.000234743067021 I, 0.871212447246 - 0.00245575865166 I, 
  1.73800643723 - 0.0000175930777835 I}, {-0.0457600565645 - 
   0.000234743067015 I, 0.871212447246 - 0.00245575865159 I, 
  1.73800643723 - 0.0000175930777835 I}, {2.85849739661 - 
   0.0205210424127 I, 1.69446366772 + 0.00423341538808 I, 
  0.43341309888 - 0.00107192620088 I}, {-2.85849739661 + 
   0.0205210424127 I, 1.69446366772 + 0.00423341538809 I, 
  0.43341309888 - 0.00107192620089 I}, {-2.85849739661 + 
   0.0205210424128 I, -1.44712898587 + 0.00423341538809 I, 
  2.70817955471 + 0.00107192620087 I}, {2.8584973966 - 
   0.0205210424129 I, -1.44712898587 + 0.00423341538815 I, 
  2.70817955471 + 0.00107192620087 I}, {2.29909450142 - 
   0.343483831742 I, 
  1.77223673582 + 0.0913139810182 I, -0.0739677998393 + 
   0.0304287559836 I}, {-2.29909450142 + 0.343483831739 I, 
  1.77223673582 + 0.0913139810173 I, -0.0739677998391 + 
   0.0304287559833 I}, {-2.29909450142 + 
   0.34348383173 I, -1.36935591777 + 
   0.0913139810147 I, -3.06762485375 - 
   0.0304287559824 I}, {2.29909450142 - 
   0.343483831728 I, -1.36935591777 + 
   0.0913139810142 I, -3.06762485375 - 
   0.0304287559822 I}, {-2.26270660962 - 0.330357852102 I, 
  1.78264003948 - 0.0895614445852 I, -0.0700047512398 - 
   0.0313783629945 I}, {-2.26270660962 - 
   0.330357852102 I, -1.35895261411 - 
   0.0895614445854 I, -3.07158790235 + 
   0.0313783629947 I}, {2.26270660963 + 0.330357852095 I, 
  1.78264003948 - 0.0895614445833 I, -0.0700047512395 - 
   0.0313783629939 I}, {2.26270660963 + 
   0.330357852095 I, -1.35895261411 - 
   0.0895614445834 I, -3.07158790235 + 
   0.0313783629939 I}, {2.02278300082 + 0.00847987195199 I, 
  1.90068573464 - 0.00239316828804 I, 
  0.334252701909 + 0.00167145305082 I}, {2.02278300081 + 
   0.00847987195193 I, -1.24090691895 - 0.00239316828803 I, 
  2.80733995168 - 0.00167145305079 I}, {-2.02278300081 - 
   0.0084798719519 I, 1.90068573464 - 0.00239316828802 I, 
  0.334252701909 + 0.0016714530508 I}, {-2.02278300081 - 
   0.0084798719518 I, -1.24090691895 - 0.00239316828798 I, 
  2.80733995168 - 0.00167145305079 I}} *)
```